# Need a little help understanding Angularjs $compile

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If you take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/waylon999/peR9P/3/ you'll see what I'm trying to do.  I'm trying to use $compile as a way to replace a template with another template.

I would expect:

```
scope.compiledVal = $compile(scope.value)(scope);
```

to compile the contents of

```
"<div>{{ name }}</div>"
```

with the binded name that is passed in with scope, then replace the compiledVal in

```
<div>{{ compiledVal }}</div>
```

with the compiled template.  This is not happening though, the output is simply

```
{{ compiledVal }}
```

and if I open up JSFiddle's console I see the error:
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: this isn't the 'angular' way to approach the issue. Longer answer: you're calling `$compile` inside the digest loop, which is causing the loop, this is fairly complex. It would be good to read up on the angular digest loop http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$digest. To dynamically switch template content, you should use something like `ng-switch` or even `ng-include`

Answer (score 0):

So in answer to my question, it looks like I could use

```
var tmp = $compile(scope.value)(scope);
element.append(tmp);
```

updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/waylon999/peR9P/3/.

But will need to re-evaluate after Alex Osborn's comment...